# Python gil strange behaviour

Tags: python, multithreading, gil

Look at this piece of code:

```
from threading import Thread
import time

cpt = 0

def myfunction():
    print("myfunction.start")
    global cpt
    for x in range(10):
        cpt += 1
        time.sleep(0.2)
        print("cpt=%d" % (cpt))
    print("myfunction.end")

thread1 = Thread(target=myfunction)
thread2 = Thread(target=myfunction)
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```

This is a very basic function which reads/write a global variable.
I am running 2 threads on this same function.

I have read that python is not very efficient with multi-threading because of GIL, which automaticly locks functions or methods which access to the same resources.
So, i was thinking that python will first run thread1, and then thread2, but i can see in the console output that the 2 threads are run in parallel.
So i do not understand what gil is really locking...

Thanks

Comment: The GIL has nothing to do with "accessing the same resources".

Comment: The GIL locks at Python byte-code level, not functions or methods.

Answer (score 2):

That's because of the `sleep` system call which releases the CPU (and even "exits" from the interpreter for a while)

when you do `time.sleep(0.2)`, the current thread is suspended by the system (not by Python) for a given amount of time, and the other thread is allowed to work.

Note that the `print` statements or `threading.current_thread()` that you could insert to spy the threads also yield (briefly) to the system so threads can switch because of that (remember [Schrodinger's cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger's_cat)). The *real* test would be this:

```
from threading import Thread
import time

cpt = 0

def myfunction():
    global cpt
    for x in range(10):
        cpt += 1
        time.sleep(0.2)
    print(cpt)

thread1 = Thread(target=myfunction)
thread2 = Thread(target=myfunction)
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```

Here you get

```
20
20
```

which means that each thread worked to increase the counter in turn.

now comment the `time.sleep()` statement, and you'll get:

```
10
20
```

which means that first thread took all the increasing, ended and let the second thread increase the further 10 counts. No system calls (even `print`) ensure that the GIL works at full.

GIL doesn't induce a *performance* problem, it just prevents 2 threads to run in parallel. If you need to really run python code in parallel, you have to use the `multiprocessing` module instead (with all its constraints, the pickling, the forking...)

Comment: Okay so GIL will only lock internal python calls ? Is there a really big performance problem with gil as i can read ? Thanks